# Issue when running Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this error message when i run rails server.

> cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext (LoadError)

Please help

[Error message snipet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsfzI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling bcrypt with `gem uninstall bcrypt` and `gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby`.

Then reinstall with `gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby` and add this to your gemfile `gem 'bcrypt', platforms: :ruby`

Comment: only that when i run bundle show bcrypt it shows could not find gem 'bcrypt'. did you mean bycrpt? That's the message it displays on the terminal and i've specified gem 'bcrypt', platforms: :ruby in my gemfile. please how do i fix this? thanks

Comment: try deleting your `gemfile.lock` and running `bundle`

Comment: i've deleted gemfile.lock and run bundle. it showed "The dependency bcrypt <>=0> will be unused by any of the platforms bundler is installing for. bundler is installingfor x86-mingw32 but the dependency is only for ruby. to add these platforms to the bundle, run bundle lock --add-platform ruby. I run bundle lock --add-platform ruby and then bundle show bcrypt. the same message still shows "could not find gem 'bcrypt' "

Comment: Just to clarify, is there still a problem with running your rails server? You initially said my answer solved your problem, but now you are no longer able to run the server. Is that correct?

Comment: rails server is running now no issues with it again. but the problem am having is that when i run bundle show bcrypt, "it shows could not find gem 'bcrypt' " even when i've included it in gemfile as you asked me to do. i will need this gem later on in my project

Comment: Okay good to know. May I suggest you accept this answer and ask a new question? That way you can share your Gemfile and we can look at this new problem in more detail.